# x cancels out when looking for extremum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

So this happenned when I was trying to find a maximum of a function $f(x)$ and I'm not sure how to interpret that. The calculations are correct, I checked multiple times. 
$$f'(x)=...=(y_1-y_2)(x-x+c)=0$$
x cancels out and it leaves me with a condition $y_1=y_2$. 
Does it mean extremum does not exist or what do I make of that?

If that's of any help this is the function. $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\rho, y_1, y_2$ are given. $\sigma_1,\sigma_2, y_1, y_2$ are positive real numbers, $\rho$ is real and $|\rho| \leq 1$.

$$f(x)=\frac{(y_1-y_2)(x-\frac{\sigma_2^2-\rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2\rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_2})}{\sqrt{x^2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2\rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_2)+x(-2\sigma_2^2+2\rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_2)+\sigma_2^2}}$$

Comment: What are $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: @Paul They are some positive real numbers, can have different values

Comment: Can you write out what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: @Paul Yes, edited the post. It's grim looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is proportional to 
$$\frac{ax+b}{\sqrt{ax^2+2bx+c}},$$

and by a linear transformation of the the variable ($t=\dfrac{ax+b}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}$), you can reduce it to 
$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}.$$
The numerator of the derivative is
$$\sqrt{t^2+1}-t\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}},$$ and the numerator of the latter $1$, which is a constant. The function has indeed no stationary point. It is S-shaped, with an inflection point and two horizontal asymptotes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I finally got a grip on this now.